# Is it possible to show images in Skype chat window?

Tags: skype

Is it possible to show images in Skype chat window ? 
(windows 7 Skype client)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can share your desktop using the windows desktop client (not Windows Modern), or drag and drop a image (or any file) into an IM window, or if you are using the iOS client do this - http://mashable.com/2012/08/21/skype-photo-sharing-update/

Update 7/9/14: More clients now support picture sharing in the chat: Xbox one, Windows Phone and iOS all have it now.

Update 09/10/14: Window and Mac too now ([improved-skype-desktop-clients-for-a-dynamic-new-chat-experience](http://blogs.skype.com/2014/10/09/improved-skype-desktop-clients-for-a-dynamic-new-chat-experience/))

Disclosure: I currently work for Microsoft/Skype

Comment: On the windows client you can paste images from the clipboard into a chat.

Answer (score 2):

I think no, only you can share links to image, if you think on showing send image immediately, without download them.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [discussion/plea](http://community.skype.com/t5/Live-Messenger/Display-Images-in-Chat-Window/m-p/2891319) for such a feature at the Skype Community. Also, there's this [Feature Suggestion](http://community.skype.com/t5/Mac/Feature-Suggestion-Inline-images/m-p/1652363#M30466) separately. Please support.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to share photos in real-time, the following tool allows for an online, collaborative slide show. I use it regularly to show pictures to my family over a skype session: http://www.photozzap.com/